# How to create a layout like Android CallLog's layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-source

Hey I want to create a layout like this for my application. Of course the functionalities will be differents. I'm studying the source code for this, and I found the xml files that does that. I just dont know how to implement that in the activity, how to call, what to create, a listview, etc.

[image]

I mean, I just want to list the name with a bigger font and the date like in the image, with a small font but aligned to the right.

Because, I want to get the data from the database I've created and print it like this list of CallLog.

I mean, how Android makes the date with that icon align in the right, with a small font size?

So this is my activity, I just dont know what xml file from the source code to use, or what method to implement so I can print the data like the image example.

```
   public class RatedCalls extends ListActivity {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "RatedCalls";
private TableLayout table;
private CallDataHelper cdh;
private TableRow row;
private TableRow row2;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.recent_calls);

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "calling from onCreate()");

    cdh = new CallDataHelper(this);

    startService(new Intent(this, RatedCallsService.class));
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Service called.");
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "before call fillList");

    /*
     * mAdapter = new RecentCallsAdapter();
     * getListView().setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
     * setListAdapter(mAdapter);
     */

    fillList();
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "after call fillList");

}

public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    fillList();

}

public void fillList() {

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "entered on fillList");
    List<String> ratedCalls = new ArrayList<String>();
    ratedCalls = this.cdh.selectTopCalls();


     //setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.recent_calls_list_item,
     //ratedCalls));


    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    getListView().setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}

 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: You're asking how to write a huge program for you. Break it down step by step. No one's going to write your code for you.

Comment: No, its not that, I just like a help, if you just tell me what to do, or some tutorial of how to implement that, its ok. Thanks.

Comment: First learn how to make a simple list then maybe we can help you with a something similar. I have no idea where to even start tellin you what you need to do

Comment: I know how to implement a listView. You can start for the best way you think. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a 2 step process:

1. Create a Layout Xml file which represents 1 item of your list.
2. Extend Array Adapter and use your custom layout file there. There are several examples on the internet on how to extend Array Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to create a listview with multiple textviews.